# Removing dtype from np.array

Tags: python, numpy

I'm trying convert a set of images into arrays using `keras.preprocessing.image.img_to_array`. When I iterate through my images, the initial arrays are what I am looking for. But when I append these arrays to a list, each array becomes a tuple and has the `dtype` shown at the end of each array. I want create a list of these arrays without them being tuples and having the `dtype` shown at the end. I'm relatively new so any help would be appreciated!

The is the code I am referring to:

```py
images = []
for imagepath in imagePaths:
    pic = image.load_img(imagepath)
    pic_array = image.img_to_array(pic)
    images.append(pic_array) 
    label = imagepath.split(os.path.sep)[-2]
    food_label.append(label)

print(images)
```

This returns as

```
[array(225., 225., 135.], ... ]], dtype=float32), array([...
```

Comment: Every array has a `dtype`.  And no, it does not become a tuple.  the `()` are part of the display..  There's nothing wrong with that list of arrays.  That's just the display format.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is based on a misunderstanding and there is no actual issue involved.

Answer (score 1):

the "dtype" is just shown by the REPL display. I assume you might be using something like Hydrogen, Jupyter Notebook or any such tool which gives an instantaneous output of the code. As stated in the comments, it is just the display format to give YOU a little idea of the variable.

It is not actually passed when the code grinds it's gears when it is executed....